# expecting output with out using left join

Tags: sql, sql-server

first table is my input and expecting output like second table  with out using left join.
this is the table data

```
declare @table table 
(customer_id int,
indicator bit,
salary numeric(22,6)
,netresult numeric(22,6))

INSERT INTO @table (
    customer_id
    ,indicator
    ,salary
    )
VALUES 
(1,1,2000),
(1,1,3000),
(2,1,1000),
(1,0,500),
(1,1,5000),
(2,1,2000),
(2,0,100)

select * from @table order by customer_id,indicator desc
```

I tried in below method it works. Is there any better alternative?

```
SELECT a.customer_id
    ,a.indicator
    ,a.salary
    ,netresult=p_salary-(2*n_salary)
FROM (
    SELECT customer_id
        ,indicator
        ,salary
        ,sum(salary) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id) p_salary
    FROM @table
    ) a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT customer_id
        ,indicator
        ,salary
        ,sum(salary) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id) n_salary
    FROM @table
    WHERE indicator = 0
    ) b ON a.customer_id = b.customer_id
    order by customer_id,indicator desc
```

**Expected Output**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
select t.customer_id, t.indicator,
       sum(case when indicator = 1 then salary else - salary end) over (partition by customer_id) as netresult
form @table t;
```

No joins are necessary.

Answer (score 1):

with math

```
select t.customer_id, t.indicator, t.salary
     , sum((( t.indicator * 2) -1) * salary) over (partition by customer_id) as netresult
from @table t;
```